# What does it mean for a series to be "about a" or "centered at a". and what about polynomial approximations?

Tags: sequences-and-series

1) What does it mean for a series to be "about a" or "centered at a".

2) I also do not understand what does it mean for representing power series as sigma C (subscript n) times (x-a) to the power of n? .. I solved many questions on radius of convergence and interval of convergence but this "(x-a) to the power of n" notation is confusing. Especially when i got to the Taylor series.

3) To understand topics conceptually, I've been using the calculus revisited videos by the great Herbert Gross. and he introduced the topic of polynomial approximation which completely went over my head. How does it work in the context of Taylor series.?