# What is the difference between saying "the taylor polynomial (or series) 'centered' at $a$", and "the taylor polynomial (or series) 'about' $a$"?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, terminology

What is the difference between saying "the taylor polynomial (or series) 'centered' at $a$", and "the taylor polynomial (or series) 'about' $a$"?

I found a similar MSE question ([What does it mean for a series to be "about a" or "centered at a". and what about polynomial approximations?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/331441/what-does-it-mean-for-a-series-to-be-about-a-or-centered-at-a-and-what-abou)), which has remained unanswered.

I would greatly appreciate it if someone could clarify any differences and illustrate with examples.

Thank you.

Comment: There is no difference. +1 for finding the (almost) duplicate. That question asks about more than the vocabulary - the OP is confused about the idea of Taylor expansion. Now that you know you can answer your own question so it doesn't remain in limbo. Maybe you can answer that one too.

Comment: No difference. These are used interchangeably.

Comment: I thank you for your assistance. :)

Comment: Well, there is a difference, "centred at" uses one word and four (or five in American spelling) letters more than "about".

Comment: @DanielFischer Illuminating.

Answer (score 1):

Like everyone pointed out sharply in the comments, the differences are mainly up to the number of letters you are willing to spend.

If it is for a tweet or for a MathExchange question title, where you have a limited number of characters, I would recommend saying "about". If you have total freedom and no restrictions on the number of characters you may use, just pick whatever you prefer.